# Puppet : Deployments to WebLogic

Tags: deployment, weblogic, puppet

Is Puppet the right tool to use to deploy ear files to WebLogic ? We recently moved to Puppet for WebLogic installation but are still using a legacy system for deployments. I wanted to find out from others whether they use Puppet for  ear/war file deployments to WebLogic and if they have any suggestions on how to go about doing the same.

While I could easily write a puppet manifest to deploy the ear file, there are a few areas I am not very clear about
1. How to setup it up such that a developer could "trigger" a deployment "on demand".
2. How to allow the developer to specify the location + name of the actual ear file

Comment: Do you use Puppet to upload the wars into WLS itself, or do you drop the files in and let WLS deploy automatically?

Comment: I need a way to push the deployment file (ear) to the target WLS admin server too.

Comment: Make a WLST script to do that. You can then trigger it via puppet, or manually via Jenkins or whatever.